How can I turn off 802.11r fast transition in Linux NetworkManager client?
I am running Debian stable (12.5), and have been experiencing sticky client issues with NetworkManager 1.42.4, and kernel 6.1.0-21-amd64. You can find a good description of the sticky client issue at this post by @vwv.
In essence, NetworkManager keeps trying to connect to the far and weaker Access Point (that I previously sat close to), rather than the very close and stronger one (where I now moved my desk). Since the far AP is pretty weak the connection keeps getting lost, and I am stuck in this connect-disconnect loop with failures to connect all along. It's getting really difficult to work under these circumstances.
Since I don't move my laptop around like a mobile phone or tablet, and don't need to roam with fast transition, I thought it would help to just turn off 802.11r Fast Transition as it is not working properly. However, there is nothing about it for a client online, in the man pages and the NetworkManager official docs. The link above does not mention how to turn it off in a client either. Can anyone help?

Are you using iwd or wpa_supplicant as the Wi-Fi backend? Is FT specifically involved in your case, or is it that NM is performing regular non-FT roaming unwanted?

My backend is wpa_supplicant.  I couldn't find any FT-specific settings in my NM conf, but NM is scanning every 2 minutes as it is supposed to. Tried sorting it out with the network admin, and they were quick to point out issues with my 802.11r. Apparently my client is the only one with this problem on the network. They refuse to help me sort it out because it seems they are "not responsible for user clients".
